# How to make a update with value from a cast?

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, postgis, geojson

I have an `INSERT INTO` query that takes an input from a html form and insert it in a table on postgres, one of the columns's value is a GeoJSON. Now i'm trying to prepare a trigger function that take the json after the `INSERT` query and convert it to geometry and insert this geometry in another column on the same table.

`SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
         ST_AsText(
           CAST(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(t1."column-name") AS TEXT)
         ), 4326
       )
FROM (SELECT "column-name"
      FROM table-name
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS t1;`

With this query i take the GeoJSON from the last row inserted and convert it to a geometry, but i don't know how to insert this geometry value in another column.

Comment: You can use a SELECT to INSERT into another table. See here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert/

Comment: There's no way to use the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to come up with a query that resolve my problem:

`UPDATE table-name 
SET column-name = (SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
         ST_AsText(
           CAST(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(t1.column-name) AS TEXT)
         ), 4326
       )
FROM (SELECT column-name
      FROM table-name
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS t1)
WHERE id IN(SELECT id
      FROM table-name
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1
);`

With this query i take a GeoJSON within, from the last row inserted in the table, and convert it to geometry and insert this geometry in another column of the same row from where i had taked the GeoJson.

Importante: the column that stores the GeoJSON has the data type of character varying.

Hope it has made sense, english is not my first language.